# Display only text field of Numeric Stepper in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Is there any property of Numeric Stepper in Flex which can be used to display only the text field of Numeric Stepper and hide the arrow buttons? I need to display the complete Numeric Stepper on Mouse Roll over.

Comment: If using a spark NumericStepper, create a custom skin with hide/show behaviour for buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flex 4 create custom skin with new state: over. Create new class NumericStepperExtends extends NumericStepper, listen rollover and rollout events, and change skin state.
NumericStepperExtends:

```
package classes
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    import spark.components.NumericStepper;

    public class NumericStepperExtends extends NumericStepper
    {

        private var _over:Boolean = false;

        public function NumericStepperExtends()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOverHandler, false, 0, true);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOutHandler, false, 0, true);
        }

        override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String
        {
            if (_over) return "over";

            return super.getCurrentSkinState();
        }

        protected function onRollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _over = false;

            invalidateSkinState();
        }

        protected function onRollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _over = true;

            invalidateSkinState();
        }
    }
}
```

Skin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
      xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minHeight="23" minWidth="40" 
      alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        [HostComponent("spark.components.NumericStepper")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["textDisplay", "decrementButton", "incrementButton"];

        /**
         * @private
         */  
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        private var cornerRadiusChanged:Boolean;
        private var borderStylesChanged:Boolean;

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if (cornerRadiusChanged)
            {
                var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
                if (incrementButton)
                    incrementButton.setStyle("cornerRadius", cr);
                if (decrementButton)
                    decrementButton.setStyle("cornerRadius", cr);
                cornerRadiusChanged = false;
            }

            if (borderStylesChanged)
            {
                textDisplay.setStyle("borderAlpha", getStyle("borderAlpha"));
                textDisplay.setStyle("borderColor", getStyle("borderColor"));
                textDisplay.setStyle("borderVisible", getStyle("borderVisible"));
                borderStylesChanged = false;
            }
        }

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
        {
            var allStyles:Boolean = !styleProp || styleProp == "styleName";

            super.styleChanged(styleProp);

            if (allStyles || styleProp == "cornerRadius")
            {
                cornerRadiusChanged = true;
                invalidateProperties();
            }

            if (allStyles || styleProp.indexOf("border") == 0)
            {
                borderStylesChanged = true;
                invalidateProperties();
            }
        }
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="over" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Button id="incrementButton" right="0" top="0" height="50%" tabEnabled="false"
              includeInLayout.normal="false" visible.normal="false" includeInLayout.over="true"
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.NumericStepperIncrementButtonSkin" />

    <s:Button id="decrementButton" right="0" bottom="0" height="50%" tabEnabled="false" 
              includeInLayout.normal="false" visible.normal="false" includeInLayout.over="true"
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.NumericStepperDecrementButtonSkin" />

    <s:TextInput id="textDisplay" left="0" top="0" right="18" bottom="0"
        skinClass="spark.skins.spark.NumericStepperTextInputSkin" />

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Don't forget add css for bind new component and new skin:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace classes "classes.*";

    classes|NumericStepperExtends
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("skins.NumericStepper");
    }


</fx:Style>
```

Comment: I'd say it would be better if the whole behaviour were located inside the skin only. That way you wouldn't have to create a custom component for something that functionally still is a NumericStepper with a different visual aspect. The skins can then easily be swapped through CSS, without having to change the component declaration.

Comment: maybe you are right, but different cases has different implementation. Component has logic about change states, skin has states. If move logic in skin, new other skins  will be duplicate code with logic. So i always choose one component - many simple views (skins).

Comment: I understand your point of view, but if code duplication is your concern, you can still encapsulate the rollover logic in a separate class and compose it into your skin. Duplication is then reduced to one line and your architecture is more flexible by [favoring composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a mask (tutorial [here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/)), what is applied when mouse is not over.

so you have to: 
1) create a masking object, 
2) mask the stepper (stepper.mask = mymask)
3) add rollover and rollout listeners to mask, where you set or remove the mask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, csomakk. But I only have to hide the arrow buttons of the Numeric Stepper and not the complete stepper.

Comment: oh, i see. than you'll have to skin, (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSA95C9644-B650-4783-B5C0-D2C7F95A23E3.html) and you can set the skin according to the rollover

Answer (score 0):

You can try a very simple way: Use mx_internal:

```
var n : NumericStepper = new NumericStepper();
n.mx_internal::nextButton.visible = false;
n.mx_internal::prevButton.visible = false;
```